# What is time complexity of below function?

Tags: sum, digits

```
    int sumOfDigits(int n)
    {

    if(n<=9)

    return n;

    else


         {  
               int r=0;
               while(n!=0)
                   {
                        r=r+n%10;
                        n=n/10;
                   }


     sumOfDigits(r);
                }

            }
```

This function finds sum of digits of a number till it becomes less than 10.
    e.g.if n=12345
    then output=6
    as 1+2+3+4+5=15,
    again 1+5=6.

Comment: you can test it by messure the runtime for different values of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you try to achieve is something like this:

```
class St2 {
    static int sumOfDigits(int n) {
        if(n<=9) {
            return n;
        }
        else {  
            int d = n%10;
            return d + sumOfDigits((n-d)/10);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(St2.sumOfDigits(345678));
    }
}
```

This would sum the digits. The complexity is linear in the number of digits thus logarithmic in the scale of the input number.

Comment: Output of your code is 33 but it should be 6.As I have to find sum of digits till it becomes less than 10.

Comment: This would not be the _sum_ of digits, but the _number_ of digits, sorry I misunderstood your English...

Comment: Regardess the misunderstanding about the output, the complexity was stated correctly as being O(logn)

Comment: yeah..I figured it out..Thanks